# What protocol does ios bluetooth GKSession use?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

UDP / TCP ?

because i need to stream data using ios GKSession. :)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Proprietary undisclosed protocol. You can stream data only between two iOS devices.